# AHK extract date from Excel, then reformat and send to another application

Tags: excel, autohotkey, date-format

I want to automate some dull task of updating start/end dates in SAP using AHK.
I have everything figured out, only thing bothering me is some date conversion/manipulation.
This is code that pulls info from active excel:

```
F3::
If !WinActive("ahk_exe EXCEL.EXE")
{
    Return
}
Xl := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
while (Xl.Range("A" . A_Index).Value != "") 
{
    if (A_Index > 1)
    {
        ORD_NUM := Xl.Range("A" . A_Index).Value 
        SAP_BED := Xl.Range("B" . A_Index).Value 
        SAP_BSD := Xl.Range("C" . A_Index).Value            
        MsgBox %SAP_BED%
    }
}
Return
```

Script pulls data just fine, but when MsgBox comes out, it says "4/15/2020", which is local DateTime format (m/d/yyyy), but for SAP I need to have date in DD.MM.YYYY format.
I have a sort of workaround where I format cells in Excel to match my desired format, then copy into Notepad and copy/paste back in Excel, but that is not final solution. I want it all through AHK. Also, I want to share this with some of my colleagues, but they might have different local format (eg. d/m/yyyy).
Example of Excel data:

```
Order   SAP_BED SAP_BSD
1001561541  15.04.2020  10.04.2020
1001561542  22.04.2020  17.04.2020
1001550809  23.04.2020  20.04.2020
```

What I believe I need is a way to turn excel value into date object in AHK, and then to use Format or FormatTime to forge my needed date format.
Any help? :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try [DateStampConvert.ahk](http://www.computoredge.com/AutoHotkey/Downloads/DateStampConvert.ahk).

Comment: I have seen it but it also asks user which date format is being used (d/m/y or m/d/y). I was hoping that there is some other way to recognize local format, and then to build based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Day`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/day-function), [`Month`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/month-function) and [`Year`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/year-function) functions:

```
SAP_BED_Xl := Xl.Range("B" . A_Index).Value
SAP_BED := Xl.Day(SAP_BED_Xl) . "." . Xl.Month(SAP_BED_Xl) . "." . Xl.Year(SAP_BED_Xl)

SAP_BSD_Xl := Xl.Range("B" . A_Index).Value
SAP_BSD := Xl.Day(SAP_BSD_Xl) . "." . Xl.Month(SAP_BSD_Xl) . "." . Xl.Year(SAP_BSD_Xl)
```

Note that the day and month don't have necessarily two digits.

Comment: I am getting this error: 
---------------------------
SAP_CO02.ahk
---------------------------
Error at line 146.

The following variable name contains an illegal character:
"Xl.Day(SAP_BED_Xl)"

The program will exit.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: Still error, now for unknown name: https://i.imgur.com/UEE5f39.png

Comment: I honestly don't know what is the problem. I mostly use AHK v2. If you find a solution, post an answer or edit mine.